# Split verilog element descriptions using regular expressions

Tags: c++, regex, delphi

Coding tool : c++ builder or delphi

In Verilog language a net list with logic cells and devices  goes like this example below:

```
xor (pin1, pin2, pin3, pin4 ..... ) ;
nmos (parameter )  (pin1, pin2, pin3) ;
xor instancename (pin1, pin2, pin3, pin4 ..... ) ;
nmos (parameter )   (pin1, pin2, pin3) ;
```

Question: How to split these text blocks if there are only 1 or sometimes 2 brackets given and the same for leading words (1  or 2 Words), from a Verilog text file, using a regular expression?

non working solution

```
\w*\s|\((.*?)\)
```

this gets the  first words, but I also need  the text inside  the brackets as a 3.rd word

Comment: This is probably best left to a full parser.

Comment: need only a solution for  this  regular expression  issue, did  the  other parsing already  on my own

Comment: This question asks multiple question at once - edit it to either wanting the regex, or how to use regex in a given language, or how to use "_the split function_". All of those problem on their own are rather trivial.